# How to accept a Message when clicked on a button

Tags: jquery

I have a functionality when user clciks on a Reject Button , he needs to enter the Reason (why he is  rejecting that )

http://jsfiddle.net/au8xd05a/1/

```
<input type="button" id="rejectcategory" class="btn blue" value="Reject This Category">
    <div id="item">
    </div>


$("#rejectcategory").click(function (e) {
var newDiv =  $("<div />"); 
var textArea = $('<textarea id="textforrej" style="padding-left:100px" />'); 
newDiv.append(textArea);
newDiv.dialog({modal: true, width:850, height:500, title:"Please Enter Reason for Rejection"});
});


$("textforrej").blur(function(){
  $("#rejectcategory").show();
});
```

This is my code , could you please let me know , once the user completes entering how can i close the dialog box and continue with the ajax call (backend operation to store the message )

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: I think `var newDiv =  $("<div />");` should be `var newDiv =  $("#item");`

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/au8xd05a/2/

You need to use the `on` function, since your textbox is live;

```
$(document).on('blur',"#textforrej",function(){
  alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
  $("#rejectcategory").show();
```

});

And you forget the `#` character befor your id in your original code.